# RHEL for educational purposes

Tags: rhel

Recently I installed free beta 8.2 of RHEL but I can’t install any packages due to subscription manager. How am I supposed to get over this?

Answer (score 5):

If you don’t have an existing RHEL subscription, and you want to run the beta for educational purposes, you can get a no-cost [developer subscription](https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/download) and use that. (See the last paragraph [of the RHEL 8.2 beta announcement](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/red-hat-enterprise-linux-82-beta-now-available).)

(Developer subscriptions aren’t limited to educational purposes, see the agreement on the site.)

Comment: I downloaded the beta version .

Comment: Nevertheless it still demands subscription

Comment: Yes, you need to use your developer subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Since its an educational purpose and only to install packages, we can use centos repo instead of RHEL.

Or we can mount the iso and use it as a local repo.

CATION: never do yum update when centos repo is enabled in RHEL os.

Comment: There’s no CentOS equivalent to the 8.2 beta...